# celery missed heartbeat (on_node_lost)

Tags: python, django, celery

I just upgraded to celery 3.1 and now I see this i my logs ::

```
on_node_lost - INFO - missed heartbeat from celery@queue_name for every queue/worker in my cluster.
```

According to the docs `BROKER_HEARTBEAT` is off by default and I haven't configured it.

Should I explicitly set `BROKER_HEARTBEAT=0` or is there something else that I should be checking?

Comment: BROKER_HEARTBEAT=0 does not fix the problem

Comment: Starting the workers without a heartbeat (--without-heartbeat) silences this avalanche of logs but I am concerned that we may be sweeping another problem under the rug

Answer (score 16):

Celery 3.1 added in the new mingle and gossip procedures. I too was getting a ton of missed heartbeats and passing --without-gossip to my workers cleared it up.

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/whatsnew-3.1.html#mingle-worker-synchronization

> #### Mingle: Worker synchronization
>
> The worker will now attempt to synchronize with other workers in the
> same cluster.
>
> Synchronized data currently includes revoked tasks and logical clock.
>
> This only happens at startup and causes a one second startup delay to
> collect broadcast responses from other workers.
>
> You can disable this bootstep using the --without-mingle argument.

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/whatsnew-3.1.html#gossip-worker-worker-communication

> #### Gossip: Worker <-> Worker communication
>
> Workers are now passively subscribing to worker related events like
> heartbeats.
>
> This means that a worker knows what other workers are doing and can
> detect if they go offline. Currently this is only used for clock
> synchronization, but there are many possibilities for future additions
> and you can write extensions that take advantage of this already.
>
> Some ideas include consensus protocols, reroute task to best worker
> (based on resource usage or data locality) or restarting workers when
> they crash.
>
> We believe that although this is a small addition, it opens amazing
> possibilities.
>
> You can disable this bootstep using the --without-gossip argument.

Comment: just a quick note FYI there is a commercial operator of rabbitmq they have recommended settings for `celery`: https://www.cloudamqp.com/docs/celery.html#commandline-arguments . they also recommend `--without-gossip`. i'm not advocating either way. i'm just offering more information that can inform your decision.

Comment: for more information on the consequences of turning off `gossip` or `mingle` or `heartbeat` please see: [what-are-the-consequences-of-disabling-gossip-mingle-and-heartbeat-for-celery-w](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55249197) and [application-impacts-of-celery-workers-running-with-the-without-heartbeat-fla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66978028)

Answer (score 12):

Saw the same thing, and noticed a couple of things in the log files.

1) There were messages about time drift at the start of the log and occasional missed heartbeats.

2) At the end of the log file, the drift messages went away and only the missed heartbeat messages were present.

3) There were no changes to the system when the drift messages went away... They just stopped showing up.

I figured that the drift itself was likely the problem itself.

After syncing the time on all the servers involved these messages went away. For ubuntu, run ntpdate as a cron or ntpd.

Comment: what do you mean by the drift?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar issue. I have found the reason in my case.

I have two server to run worker.

when I use **"ping"** to another server,
I found when the ping time larger than 2 second, the log will show **" missed heartbeat from celery@ "**. The default heartbeat interval is 2 second.

The reason is my poor network.
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/reference/celery.worker.heartbeat.html

Comment: Could you modify the heartbeat interval?

Comment: yes, celery has --heartbeat-interval parameter.[--heartbeat-interval](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.worker.html)

Answer (score -1):

add --without-mingle when you start celery

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.